# Laravel route setup for React Router with multiple path

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router-dom

I want to build an Inventory app, everything was smooth until i want to make a page with URL pattern like

```
http://localhost:8000/product/edit/1
```

So i have this route in my React Router

```
<Route path='/product/edit/:product_id' component={MyComponent} />
```

Im using **Redux** to handle the state and **Axios** to get the data.
The problem is when i call the **API** , it's calling an URL of `http://localhost:8000/product/edit/api/get-product-by-id`. Of course im not getting any data returned.

The question is how to setup the Laravel Route for this problem?
Here is my *web.php* file

```
Route::get('/{path?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('path', '^((?!api).)*?');
```

Comment: I also tried to change the _web.php_ into this `Route::get('/{path?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('path', '.*');`

Comment: `Route::view('/{path?}', 'index');` ofcourse this will simply works, but you have to call the api routes only in axios and you need to manage states on your frontend, don't interrupt frontend routes with the laravel api routes.

Comment: Yeah i already try this too, but still doesn't work

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/product/edit/api/get-product-by-id` this is wrong, it should be something like this `http://localhost:8000/api/product/edit/get-product-by-id`

Comment: I know its wrong, thats why i dont get any result. The pattern you give in comment also wrong, it should be like `http://localhost:8000/api/get-product-by-id`, i call it in *axios* , but the *axios* read the url to be `http://localhost:8000/product/edit/api/get-product-by-id`. Why the laravel API routes become this pattern when we call it in *axios*. Am i missing something in webpack config? or something else

Comment: have you tested it on postman `http://localhost:8000/api/get-product-by-id` ? also share your react routing structure

Comment: Yeah its working if i test in postman

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using this approach?
I hope this solves your problem.

```php
Route::get('/product/edit/{id}', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```